# A linked list to alphabetize strings

Tags: c, linked-list

In the lab work I am doing, it is supposed to allow a user to input strings into a linked list one by one until the user doesn't input a string. At this point the program will then compare each string by the first letter, alphabetize them, and then display them.

I know I have to use strcmp to compare two strings at a time, I've tried to understand this but it is just so complicated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define StringLengthMAX 80

struct node_link
{
    //char node_string[StringLengthMAX];
    int num;
    struct node_link *next;
};

int compare_node(struct node_link *b1, struct node_link *b2)
{
    //strcmp(*b1, *b2);


    if (b1 -> num < b2 -> num)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (b1 -> num == b2 -> num)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (b1 -> num > b2 -> num)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

struct node_link *add_node(struct node_link *list, struct node_link *node)
{
    struct node_link *cur_node=list;

    //case 1 : When list->num > node->num
    if (compare_node(list, node) == 1)
    {
        node -> next = list;
        list = node;
        return list;
    }
    // case 2

    while(cur_node->next != NULL)
    {
        if (compare_node(cur_node->next,node) == 1)
        {
            node -> next = cur_node -> next;
            cur_node->next = node;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
              cur_node = cur_node -> next;
        }
    }
    // case 3 : node->next is the greatest
    if (cur_node -> next == NULL)
    {
        cur_node->next = node;
    }
    return list;
}

void display_newlist(struct node_link *head)
{
    struct node_link *node=head;
    while(node != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d", node->num);
        node = node->next;
        printf(" ");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    struct node_link *head;
    struct node_link *node;

    node = (struct node_link*)malloc(sizeof(struct node_link));

    node->num = a;
    node->next = NULL;
    head = node;

    do
    {
        puts("Please enter any number of integers, end inputs with a ZERO (0): ");
        scanf("%d", &a);

        node = (struct node_link*)malloc(sizeof(struct node_link));
        node->num = a;
        node->next = NULL;
        head = add_node(head,node);
    }while(a != 0);

    display_newlist(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It will be simpler if you separate the logic. First, create a linked list library that allows you to insert arbitrary elements and traverse over the list. *Then* write your `add_*` function and have it use your previously written linked list code to access your linked list

Comment: The function: `compare_node` has a execution path that does not end in a `return value`; statement.  This error in the logic causes the compiler to raise the warning: 31:1: warning; control reaches end of non void function [-Wreturn-type]

Comment: in the `main()` function, the variable `a` is not initialized so this line: `node->num = a;` is placing an unknown 'trash` value into the first node.

Comment: In C, when calling any of the memory allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned value type is `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.   Casting the returned type just clutters the code, making it much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of function, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: in the main()` function,  it is best practice to always initialize the local variables.  for the two lines: `struct node_link *head;
    struct node_link *node;`  suggest: `struct node_link *head=NULL;
    struct node_link *node=NULL;`

Comment: in the function: `add_node()`, the case 2+case 3 can result in the new node being inserted twice into the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by this way

1- Replace that `int num` with any array of character

2- in compare function try to compare elements of the char array using `strcmp` function then return values according to that from `compare()` function.

3- Replace evry `num` by array of character variable